# What do you call those roofs you usually find at the entrance of buildings?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Here are some pictures (see the red arrow):

[image: Multi-storey building with lots of windows. It is the school of Biological Sciences. There is a red arrow pointing to an overhang made from metal poles.]

*In the second picture is the platform with the little trees growing on top.*

[image: Same building as above, but the picture is taken further back. There are palm trees and some bushes at the sides. The overall building is much taller than in the other photo. The left wing has "Collefe of Science" written at the top.]

What are they called?

Comment: Could you perhaps indicate more precisely the architectural structure with an arrow? Or crop the second image more tightly? Most online editing programmes have this feature, you could even use Microsoft Paint. Otherwise you're going to get a bunch of mixed answers.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A The pictures are copyrighted, can I still do that? No idea what they are called in Spanish.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A OK I included the arrows.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A Ha, because I'm at work. They only have paint. I'll make better ones once I get home.

Comment: You can vary the thickness of brush in Paint

Comment: @Mari-LouA You're right I forgot about that. How about now?

Comment: Related: [Term for a side motor entrance?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/393507)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perhaps a **canopy**?

> 2. *Architecture* An ornamental rooflike projection over a niche, altar, or tomb.
> 3. A protective rooflike covering, often of canvas, mounted on a frame over a walkway or door.

Or an **awning**?

> A rooflike structure, often made of canvas or plastic, that serves as a shelter, as over a storefront, window, door, or deck.

Comment: [Canopy](https://www.google.com/search?q=canopy&rlz=1C1AFAB_en___IT446&es_sm=122&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=jqIzVO_4N9GS7AbGjIH4CA&ved=0CAkQ_AUoAg&biw=1366&bih=653) and [architectural canopy](https://www.google.com/search?q=canopy&rlz=1C1AFAB_en___IT446&es_sm=122&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=jqIzVO_4N9GS7AbGjIH4CA&ved=0CAkQ_AUoAg&biw=1366&bih=653#tbm=isch&q=architectural%20canopy&revid=46118955&imgdii=_)

Comment: This answer is not specific to entryways (although a porch can be over an entrance).

Answer (score 13):

The word is *portico* -

- "A porch or entrance to a building consisting of a covered and often columned area" - [WordWeb](http://www.wordwebonline.com/search.pl?w=portico)
- "[A] porch leading to the entrance of a building, or extended as a colonnade, with a roof structure over a walkway, supported by columns or enclosed by walls." - [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portico)

Answer (score 4):

A modern example at a hospital

A porte-cochère

coach gate or carriage porch is a covered porch-like structure at a main or secondary entrance to a building through which originally a horse and carriage and today a motor vehicle can pass to provide arriving and departing occupants protection from the elements. [Source, Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Porte-coch%C3%A8re)

Comment: We like to see a source with a link.  I provided it for you.  +1 for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

The normal word is porch. From Latin porticus. See

http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=porch&allowed_in_frame=0

Comment: Porch eaves are typically supported by two columns, one on either side of the porch; and the eave typically has a light fixture mounted on it. The eave esentially functions as a porch roof and ceiling.

Answer (score 1):

If the space on top of the "platform" is accessible from inside the building, the term "terrace" would be appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

A portico is the structure that gives shelter to those getting into or out of a carriage at a buildings entrance. It is a low roof on columns but without walls allowing the carriage to drive through.

EC

Comment: Probalby the right answer, but on SE , an answer is supposed to give some sort of reference. See the Q&a for that.