# Term for a side motor entrance?

Tags: terminology, architecture

Sometimes in movies I see an architectural feature of hotels or large houses that have a side motor entrance or drop-off for cars with a roof as shown below:

[image: motor entrance]

Is there an architectural term for this thing?

Comment: I'm thinking that there's another term for this, at least in the US.  Something along the lines of "carriage portico".  (I see that "carriage porch" is suggested by the Wikipedia article for porte-cochère, a word that is not commonly used in the US, outside of architect's offices.)

Comment: Architects may well have another term for it, but *covered entrance* works for most of us. *Pull-though* is another option.

Comment: Making up terms, I might call it a "drop-off," since the point of it appears to be to drop off a passenger. If context were already established, I suspect most people could understand me, even though the term is definitely not common usage or instantly recognizable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What do you call those roofs you usually find at the entrance of buildings?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/200149/what-do-you-call-those-roofs-you-usually-find-at-the-entrance-of-buildings)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There may be other names, the one I am familar with is **Porte cochere**

> [Definition of porte cochere](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/porte%20cochere) Merriam-Webster
>
> 1 :  a passageway through a building or screen wall designed to let
> vehicles pass from the street to an interior courtyard
>
> 2 :  a roofed structure extending from the entrance of a building over
> an adjacent driveway and sheltering those getting in or out of
> vehicles

By way of further confirmation, here is the listing for the [pictured property, Ivy Road House, Atlanta](https://www.houzz.co.uk/projects/145065/ivy-road-house-atlanta-georgia) on the designer's website.

> This distinctive painted brick Atlanta Residence was built to maximize its narrow lot by organizing the site with a circular drive that leads to a formal front entry and a porte-cochere that leads to a more informal side entrance.

Comment: I do see that now.. so sorry

Comment: At least two of the commenters at MW said they encountered this on architectural drawings, so plus one, even though I've never heard it either (nor had some of the people claiming to be valets).

Comment: Well, I guess if I had a house that looked like that, I would call it a *porte cochere*, too. :)

Answer (score 36):

Derived from the French *porte-cochère* mentioned in Spagirl's answer, I've mostly commonly heard this termed as the anglicized [**carport**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carport).

Carport is defined by [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/carport?utm_campaign=sd&utm_medium=serp&utm_source=jsonld) as:

> an open-sided automobile shelter by the side of a building

Comment: Yes, this term is very common in the US (+1). It's probably worth noting that a carport doesn't necessarily lead anywhere (like the garages shown in the OP's picture); it can be more of an open-air attached-garage, the main place where a car is parked, rather than a pass-through.

Comment: this is definitely not a carport. This is a covered driveway entrance.  A carport is found on lower-end homes in place of a garage.

Comment: This is not a carport. A carport is where you park the car.

Comment: @Jim, see the first picture on the linked Wikipedia page, captioned "_Carport_ in front of garages" [emphasis mine].

Comment: @Emma Dash, many people park their cars on their driveways in front of the garage, including those with carports.

Comment: For 60+ years that I know of a "carport" has been an open-sided shed attached to the side of the house or adjacent to it, and built over the driveway or over a slab that extends from the driveway.  The purpose is to park the car, similar to a garage.  The structure pictured above does vaguely resemble a carport, and many people, reaching for a word, might call it that, but the purpose of the above structure is as an entry portico, not for vehicle storage (at least not if the garages visible behind it are not already filled to bursting with tools and garden equipment).

Comment: @Jim Carport usage depends more on geography and weather than on the quality or price of the home.

Comment: I thought a carport is a place to *park* the car, not an entrance to the building that a driver might stop at to let the passenger out and then park elsewhere. Note that in the picture, there is a garage separated from the house behind the drop off area.

Comment: The problem here is that the carport is and was a *Porte cochere* where the driveway stops. In the suburbs carports were placed on lots that were not deep enough for a driveway and garage. ( http://nla.gov.au/nla.obj-150231396/view ) This is where people get the idea that its different than a coach portal. But there is no requirement that a carport be at the end of the driveway, especially considering they rarely have walls except when they are attached to a side door of a house.

Answer (score 2):

**side entrance**

Whether or not the pictured structure is a carport or a garage, what it provides that's an important feature is a **side entrance** to the house.  This enables groceries, laundry, and the like to be taken into the house from a side door rather than the main entrance to the house.

In a hotel it might be called a **drop-off**, which allows taxis and other vehicles to drive to a side door underneath a roof and off main street, to avoid traffic jams in front of the hotel entrance.

Answer (score 0):

Since the example in the picture appears to have no gate, but is more of an ornamental entrance for cars to enter one or more [garages](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/garage), I might call it an **archway**.

> An arched or vaulted passage.

- OED

My understanding based on searching a few definitions is that a **carport** is often the final destination of the car, not a mere passageway.

Of interest is this article outlining the distinctions between a **garage** and a **carport**:

> The International Residential Code (IRC) and Florida Building Code (FBC) have a very specific way of defining the difference between carport and garage:
>
> **R309.2 Caports**.  Caports shall be open on at least two sides... Carports not open at least two sides shall be considered a garage.

- [McGarry And Madsen](http://www.mcgarryandmadsen.com/inspection/Blog/Entries/2017/3/18_What_is_the_difference_between_a_carport_and_a_garage.html)

It is because the example provided is not designed to be a resting place for the car but rather a passageway that I believe **archway** appropriately describes the architecture.

Here's an example use of **archway** from *[The Great Gatsby](https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&pid=sites&srcid=bWVubG9hdGhlcnRvbmhzLmNvbXxtcnMtYmVyZ2hvdXNlLWVuZ2xpc2gtMjAxM3xneDo0MjM5ZDNlNjFlNjExM2Ey)*:

> It was a photograph of half a dozen young men in blazer loafing in an **archway** through which were visible a host of spires.  There was Gatsby, looking a little, not much, youger--with a cricket bat in his hand.

Comment: The thing shown in the question is neither arched nor vaulted, so I don't see the relevance of "archway". In any case, while some of these things might be arched, that's hardly a defining feature of them. "Archway" seems no more generally applicable than, say, "white-painted thing" would be.

Comment: @DavidRicherby To be fair the structure does show a very flat elliptical arch. Given that the roof is probably trussed, I'd expect the arch to be decorative rather than structural.