# Which word should be used to describe this kind of gate [See the picture]?

Tags: single-word-requests

It is a gate to the yard of the building.
(Please correct me if there is a proper way to call the area surrounded by the building.)

[image]

Comment: I can't see any gate but there could be one out of sight at the back. I would call it an **entrance**.

Comment: ... or _entry_. But these are very hypernymic terms. Perhaps 'Entry to the courtyard' or even 'tunnel entrance' might be used as attempts to specify, but they're still not precise.

Comment: Related: [What do you call those roofs you usually find at the entrance of buildings?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/200149/what-do-you-call-those-roofs-you-usually-find-at-the-entrance-of-buildings)

Comment: "Porte cochere" is the term sought: a passageway through a building or screen wall designed to let vehicles pass from the street to an interior courtyard. https://english.stackexchange.com/a/393509/349876

Comment: In Texas, this structure is often referred to as a [***breezeway***](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/breezeway), which Merriam-Webster defines as "a roofed often open passage connecting two buildings (as a house and a garage_ or halves of a building."

Comment: @SvenYargs this is a passage connecting two spaces, not two buildings, which seems fundamentally different?

Comment: @LPH Ha, the shit I got for that answer was remarkable. The worst comments were deleted but there is still a flavour of the disdain remaining.

Answer (score 1):

In Scotland such an entrance is termed a *pend*. It's a useful word that does not seem to have found application the rest of Britain.

"An arch, an archway; an arched or vaulted roof or canopy; the vaulted ground floor of a tower or fortified building; a covered passage or entry; (in later use) especially one leading off a street frontage."

[Oxford Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/pend)

or see [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/pend)